# Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl-dev',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

I am facing problem while installing rvm 2.6.3

```
Installing required packages: libssl-dev....
Error when running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libssl-dev',
please read /home/tanmay/.rvm/log/1568568674_ruby-2.6.3/package_install_libssl-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

And then I tried to install libssl-dev.It wasn't installed.. I got this error:

```
Package libssl-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl-dev' has no installation candidate
```

what should I do now?

Comment: I do not think this should be closed as a non-programming question.  Although it looks at first glance like a Debian question, it's really a Ruby installation (via rvm) question, which is on-topic.  Details: The problem is that rvm, while compiling Ruby, sees a missing library.  It expects that library to be in the Debian package `libssl-dev`, but it does not see that library in the OP's Debian.  That said, I'll be surprised if there isn't an existing question that covers this.

Comment: The first issue says `please read /home/tanmay/.rvm/log/1568568674_ruby-2.6.3/package_install_libssl-dev.log`. So what's in there?

Answer (score 37):

Here is the solution for Ubuntu 19+

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
add deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: If you're on Debian you might need to add the keyserver as well


`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`

Comment: This works. Just wanted to add, I was on Ubuntu 20, so instead bionic-security, tried focal-security, which did not work. So, just keep bionic-security (maybe bionic's SSL library is the preferred version) for focal i.e. Ubuntu 20 too.

Comment: The important part here is that for Debian systems, you need to add @user1491929's comment before you try to do anything with libssl1.0-dev

Comment: I needed to do what was suggested in @user1491929's comment for the steps in this answer to work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, but I had to add the "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" in sources.list file.

Comment: This should be a comment.